# Remove date from filename UNIX

Tags: unix

I am working in `UNIX` and trying to write the following commands. I am receiving a source file daily whose filename is in the format :

```
ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR_20170707.
```

Since I am receiving a file daily, the file name would change based on the current date, so `ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR_20170708, ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR_20170709 etc.` I need to strip the date out of the filename and rename it to `ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR.` After I have finished whatever data reading and processing I need to do, I need to change the file name back to `ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR_20170707` for example. So since the file is being delivered daily, I cant hard code the date in whatever commands I write. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which unix-based operating system are you working on? What shell are you using? What toolchain do you have access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your toolchain, this may be as simple as running:

```
$ mv ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR_$(date +%Y%m%d) ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR
```

... before running the rest of your script, assuming you're using a Bash-like shell.

Having said that, you can just drop in `ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR_$(date +%Y%m%d)` into your script when trying to access your file instead.

This is all assuming the script's run the same day and in the same time zone as the file is downloaded.

Comment: Hi Jules, This works great and is a good start. So after I have run this command, what happens is it gets taken by my software and some data processing is done on the file. After I have finished this process(it obviously doesn't matter what that process is), how do I change file name back to the original with the date? Thanks for your help

Comment: You would have to store the current date in a variable, which you could later access when renaming the file for a second time. If you can guarantee that the processing the file will finish the same day, you can just reverse the argument to the original `mv` call. Again, though, this feels like a situation where you could produce more readable code by simply accessing the file using `ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR_$(date +%Y%m%d)` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using **bash** and you had the file name in a variable, you could do:

```
IN="ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR_20170707"
echo ${IN:0:23}
```

to give ONSITE_EXTR_ONSITE_EXTR

Googling gives all sorts of guides [here](http://tldp.org/guides.html)...